# About Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

How to record a Autosuggest box in a application through Selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

You may have some success using a combination of mouseDownAt, mouseUpAt and waitForElementPresent.

e.g.

```
mouseDownAt,id=autoSuggestInput,5,5
mouseUpAt,id=autoSuggestInput,5,5
waitForElementPresent, css=.autoSuggestLink
```

Can you provide a link to the demo page of the auto suggest script you're using

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo script using "http://jquery.bassistance.de/" Base URL. So please check following script for this.

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/autocomplete/demo/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForText</td>
    <td>id=suggest1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typeKeys</td>
    <td>id=suggest1</td>
    <td>Ad</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForText</td>
    <td>css=li.ac_even.ac_over</td>
    <td>Ada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>xpath=/x:html/x:body/x:div[2]/x:ul/x:li[1]</td>
    <td>Ada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>xpath=/x:html/x:body/x:div[2]/x:ul/x:li[2]</td>
    <td>Adamsville</td>
</tr>
```